# selenium ChromeWebDriver: unable to set cookie

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, docker-compose, selenium-chromedriver, python-3.6

I have a web scraper I am developing which needs the use of selenium-chrome to render out the javascript. most of the functionality is working well when using the docker selenium/standalone chrome image but when switching to the selenium grid to enable parralel data collection the cookies are not able to be added to the browser. The cookie in question is to disable an age check on a product website so nothing to complicated.

Versions:

3.141.59-titanium

Selenium: 3.141.59
Google Chrome: 76.0.3809.87
ChromeDriver: 76.0.3809.68
Mozilla Firefox: 68.0.1
GeckoDriver: 0.24.0

python 3.6.9
selenium 3.141.0 -from pypi

I have tried various different cookies and have tried different versions of the selenium docker grid without luck.

```
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://selenium-hub:4444/wd/hub',
desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
try:
    driver.get("https://www.google.com") 
    driver.add_cookie(cookie_dict={'name':'foo','value':'bar'}))
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Here are the errors showing in the log

```
File "testSelenium.py", line 39, in <module>
print(driver.add_cookie(cookie_dict={'name':'bob','value':'boo','path':'/'}))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 894, in add_cookie
self.execute(Command.ADD_COOKIE, {'cookie': cookie_dict})
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.UnableToSetCookieException: Message: unable to set cookie
(Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.87)
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `add_cookie` has no named parameters:

> add_cookie(cookie_dict)
>
> Adds a cookie to your current session.

See the api for further explanations: [7.20 Remote WebDriver -> add_cookie](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.add_cookie)

The correct usage would be

```
driver.add_cookie({'name':'foo','value':'bar'}))
```